# World Space Texture Setup

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, texture-coordinates

I am quite new to shaders in blender and don't know how most things work, but knowing texturing is the needed basics that I must know.

How do I create a world space texture that doesn't depend on any UV and their scale, rotation.

Here is my shader setup for the material:

[image]

Here is an example of stretching, direction change occurring on my objects.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: While it would be great to actually see how those *"wrong rotation or stretching"* look like on a screenshot, Generated texture coordinates depend on bounding box. So if bounding box is stretched in one side (e.g. scaled by one axis several times more than by others) so will be the coordinates

Comment: How would I be able to project the texture around the object without it depending on the scale or any of the coordinates. I have also heard the term "triplanar projection" which can project same texture around the whole object UV free, which is probably the same thing, however I don't understand blender shaders too much to do so.